# How to iterate pages in a JFace Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, wizard

I have a Wizard consisting of 3 pages
page1, page2 which are used to create an object when user clikcs on Next button from page2
Note: only when pages page1, page2 are complete the Finish button is enabled.

When user clicks on Next button from page2 , page3 opens showing the summary of the created object and a swt link which says "Create More Objects" , and by clicking the link the wizard should start from page1 --> page2 --> page3 ...

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `WizardPage` you can do:

```
IWizard wizard = getWizard();

IWizardPage nextPage = wizard.getPage("first page name");

wizard.getContainer().showPage(nextPage);
```